# How to draw right side up triangle recursively with ONE argument

Tags: python, recursion

Write a recursive function called draw_triangle() that outputs lines of *'s to form a right side up isosceles triangle. Function draw_triangle() has **one** parameter, an integer representing the base length of the triangle. Assume the base length is always odd and less than 20. Output 9 spaces before the first '*' on the first line for correct formatting.

Hint: The number of '*' increases by 2 for every line drawn.

Ex: If the input of the program is: `3`,

Then the function draw_triangle outputs:

```
         *
        ***
```

If the input of the program is `19`,

Then the function outputs

```
         *
        ***
       *****
      *******
     *********
    ***********
   *************
  ***************
 *****************
*******************
```

No space is output before the first asterisk on the last line when the base length is 19.

I was able to code this non-recursively as follows:

```
def draw_triangle(n):
    lines_to_print = int(((n // 2) + 1))
    spaces_to_print = 9
    asts_to_print = 1
    for i in range(lines_to_print):
        print(spaces_to_print * ' ', end='')
        print(asts_to_print * '*', end='')
        print()
        spaces_to_print -= 1
        asts_to_print += 2

base_length = int(input())
draw_triangle(base_length)
```

But I cannot, for my life, figure out how to do it recursively, let alone with only one argument. What am I missing about recursion?

Comment: the main idea behind the recursion is to subtract 2 from your n after each step until you are at 0 or below for an upside-down triangle. maybe this can give you an idea of how to do it the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

By printing after the recursion itself happens, you can print smaller lines over the bigger lines:

```py
def draw_triangle(n):
    spaces = 9 - n // 2  # Ensures correct spacing for each line
    if n == 1:
        print(spaces * ' ' + '*')
    else:
        draw_triangle(n-2)
        print(spaces * ' ' + n * '*')


draw_triangle(19)
```

Comment: I don't understand how it's possible to print after the recursion, and I wouldn't have a clue how to use that practically. It seems so complicated

Answer (score 1):

The simple trick here is to use the [str.center()](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.center) method.

```
def draw_triangle(n):
    if n == 1:
        print('*'.center(19))
    else:
        draw_triangle(n-2)
        print((n*'*').center(19))
```

Test it:

```
draw_triangle(19)

         *         
        ***        
       *****       
      *******      
     *********     
    ***********    
   *************   
  ***************  
 ***************** 
*******************
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is is to define functions to print the symbole you want to use and the spaces between them:

```
def print_ecart(ecart):
     
    if (ecart == 0):
        return;
    print(" ", end = "")
    print_ecart(ecart - 1)

def print_etoile(etoile):
    if(etoile == 0):
        return
    print("* ", end = "")
 
    print_etoile(etoile - 1)
    
def pattern(n, num):  
    if (n == 0):
        return
    print_ecart(n - 1)
    print_etoile(num - n + 1)
    print("");
    pattern(n - 1, num)
```

In this case `print_ecrat` prints spaces and `print_etoile` prints the stars:

```
pattern(10,10)
```

returns:

```
         * 
        * * 
       * * * 
      * * * * 
     * * * * * 
    * * * * * * 
   * * * * * * * 
  * * * * * * * * 
 * * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * *
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is a quite interesting question.
The main obstacle is that you have to preserve initial base length of triangle.
You can't save it via assigning input value to another parameter inside a recursive function because:

1. only one argument is allowed
2. assigning will work every function call.

Not sure if the following code is convenient with the conditions of the task but it may be useful to illustrate an idea of recursive functions for you:

```
base_length = 20
def draw_triangle(base=base_length):
    if base % 2 == 0:
        base = base - 1
        draw_triangle(base)
    else:
        if base > 0:
            # print(base)
            # print(int(base/2 - 1))
            print(' '*int((base - 2)/2+1) + '*'*(base_length - base) + ' '*int((base - 2)/2))
            base = base - 2
            draw_triangle(base)

        elif base == 0:
            return 0

draw_triangle(base=base_length)
```

Formally there is only one argument in this recursive function, but you have to define `base_length` paramater outside of the function and the function uses `base_length` inside.

Answer (score 0):

Based on others' answers, here is a recursive solution that **has only `length` as its parameter**:

```py
base_length = 0


def draw_triangle(length: int):
    global base_length
    if base_length == 0:
        base_length = length
    if length > 1:
        draw_triangle(length - 2)
    print(('*' * length).center(base_length))
    if base_length == length:
        base_length = 0
```